# How to resolve busy resource in BluePrism to run a process in the control room?

Tags: session, resources, blueprism, rpa

I want to run a process from the control room. On dragging the process to the only resource I have available, I get the error message: [Resource] is too busy to run that process. I have retired the other processes I used to run in the control room, set the business objects I use in the process I want to run as Exclusive to get highest priority, but I am still not able to run my process because my resource is still busy. How can I solve this? 
Screenshot here: [Busy Resource](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fuORz.png)

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the most common cause of that error is that there is "pending" session already waiting for the resource. Remove all filters from the bottom view and check if there's no pending session waiting for your "start" action.

Comment: I didn't have any pending session waiting for the resource. I decided to run other processes, and my resource was able to run these processes. However, when I drag and drop the original process I wanted to run, I get the "[Resource] is too busy to run this process" error method. Why am I getting this error message for this specific process?

Comment: Okay, I thought I cleared all of my filters, but I forgot about the start time. When I cleared that one, I saw that there were pending items still there, which I ran and completed. This solved my original problem.